# How can I render one component conditionally twice and not lose internal states/unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have one component which needs to be rendered conditionally. Renders the same component with different styles. So, I did like this

```
import ComponentToRender from '../../ComponentToRender'

const Main =()=> {

const [expand,setExpand] =useState(false)

 return (
<div>
 {!expand  && <ComponentToRender {...someProps} />} 
 {expand && <div>
    <ComponentToRender {...otherProps} />
</div>
}
 <button onClick={()=>setExpand(pre => !pre)}>Expand</button>
</div>

 
)
}
```

For the above code, I get what I want in terms of UI. But, all the internal states are lost. I must render two components like that and keep the internal states. Is that possible to do that in React?

Comment: Given your example you could compute props before render const props = expand ? someProps: otherProps and pass it to ComponentToRender since its the same in both cases

Comment: Do you want to have two different instances of `ComponentToRender`, each with their own state, or share the same state between the two?

Answer (score 1):

The [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) algorithm is such that when on next render you move from one component to component of different type (assuming they have same spot in component hierarchy), instance of old component is destroyed.

Since you have `<ComponentToRender/>` and another one is `<div><ComponentToRender/></div>`, they are different components (because one is inside a `div`).

Read about reconciliation.

What you can do is move the state of `ComponentToRender` to `Main` and pass it as props. Now even if the component unmounts the state will not be lost.

Comment: What if the second component is wrapped with another container? That is actually how I need to use it. Will it still work?

Comment: My bad. Just updated it. I think the component will be unmounted with the updated code. I need to keep the states

Comment: @NyiNyiHmueAung check update

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by keeping the component rendered unconditionally and hiding it with CSS.
You get to preserve Component‘s state for free along with the DOM state (scroll, focus, and input position). However, this solution has drawbacks, too:

- You mount the component on startup, even if the user never accesses it.
- You update the component even when it’s invisible.

```
import ComponentToRender from "../../ComponentToRender";

const Main = () => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ display: expand ? null : "none" }}>
        <ComponentToRender {...someProps} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: !expand ? null : "none" }}>
        <div>
          <ComponentToRender {...otherProps} />
        </div>
      </div>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => setExpand((pre) => !pre)}>Expand</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This does work. But, too laggy, so, I probably can't use this approach. Since the component is pretty big. Thanks for sharing the knowledge anyway. Appreciate it